# Duplicate UserName - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estou em um projeto em andamento, hoje já foi instalado o entity framework.
Porém o que ocorreu, ele naõ deixa adicionar usuários com o mesmo nome, o que não faz sentido nenhum, já que podem ter nomes iguais.

Para inserir é chamado este código:

```
  var resultado = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, usuario.Password).Result;
```

E se já existir um usuário com este nome, ele retorna um erro:

> user name 'name' is already taken.

Existe alguma forma de contornar isso, ou remover isso de deixar incluir apenas uma vez o mesmo nome?
Se eu adicionar um caractere só para inserir, e depois der um update, pode ocasionar algum problema ??

Comment: Esse user e a "classe" login no EF, você não pode ter 2 logins iguais no sistema, se o que você quer e o FullName do usuário por que não cria uma classe própria para ele?

Comment: @João ah sim, o projeto que foi feito desta maneira, neste caso só trocar, de inicio, eu faço uma verificação, salvo, e depois dou update pra deixar incluir  com o mesmo nome, foi uma forma que encontrei, não sei se é a melhor, porém foi a forma que encontrei rapidamente.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é você fazer um getByEmail(email) e validar se já existe. Exemplo:

```
    public Task<bool> CheckEmailInUse(string email, int? ignoreId)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(w => w.Email == email)
                    .Where(w => (!ignoreId.HasValue || ignoreId.Value != w.Id))
                    .AnyAsync();
    }
```

com isso você pode ignorar o id do mesmo user.